# https get request python (HTTPS / SSL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, python-requests

So i'm working on converting a java program I have over to python. In my java code I have a http get call that looks like this.

```
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } }, new SecureRandom());
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(sslContext)).build();

            String authString = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(envURL);
            httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

            CloseableHttpResponse httpGetResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            HttpEntity entityResponse = httpGetResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entityResponse);
            EntityUtils.consume(entityResponse);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            thresholdContent = (JSONArray) parser.parse(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i'm trying to find the cleanist way to do this in python 3.x. Or I guess the standered for doing something like this in python.

I've tried soemthing like:

```
conn = requests.get(env, headers={"content-type":"application/json"}, auth=(userName,password))
```

but have not had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

With requests in python you need to pass the url

`conn = requests.get(url = 'https://myurl', headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'})`